# How to get Map collection out of a list?

Tags: apex, map, list, iteration

I currently have a multi-demensional map/list object that is defined like this:

```
Map <Id,List <Map <Id,Custom_Inventory__c> >> complexMap = getComplexMapObject();
```

The object was difficult to create but it works perfectly fine, the first Id is AccountId, and the second index is ProductId.

Now I need a method that uses this object to verify if a record has a matching Account and Product Id within this collection. The first check is easy, something like this:

```
if(!complexMap.containsKey(line_item.Account__c)){
    return FALSE;
}
```

The question I have is about the deeper index. I know I can loop through the map list within but wondering if I have to loop if I know what index I'm looking for. For example:

```
for (Map <Id,Custom_Inventory__c> inventoryMap : complexMap.get(variable.Account__c) ) {
    // Iterate through inventoryMap, but I already know which 
    // index within this map I need... variable.Product__c)
    if(inventoryMap.containsKey(rsLineItem.Product__c)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

If I can avoid the above loop I would like to. It will never be a very large loop but if I can avoid it I think its for the better.

Comment: Why is the inner collection `List<Map>` instead of just `Map`? If it weren't for that I would say your life would be a lot easier with complex keys instead of complex data structure.

Comment: I needed the list because I have multiple products under the same Account, so I can't have multiple index entries of Account - Product maps. So this makes it possible to have an index of all related products by account. Open to other ideas but this is currently working.

Comment: Isn't the `Map` key the `Product` id though? So `Map<Id, Map<Id, Custom_Inventory__c>>` seems sufficient. Or if you have multiple matches, use `Map<Id, Map<Id, List<Custom_Inventory__c>>>`. Or better yet `Map<DualIdKey, List<Custom_Inventory__c>>`.

Comment: Last time I had this issue the `DualIdKey` idea was the perfect solution. In this instance I have 2 separate checks I need though, if the account is not part of the program then I need to flag it, and then if it is then I need to verify the products for that account are within the program. Originally I tried `<Map Id, Map<Id, Custom_Inventory__c>>` but had trouble verifying if a product exist within a specific account. Not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a `contains` check, then an additional, set holding all the ProductId values would be the simplest approach to avoiding the iteration over the AccountId values and would probably make the code a bit clearer too. The set could be generated from the `complexMap` using:

```
Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
for (List<Map<Id, Custom_Inventory__c>> l : complexMap.values()) {
    for (Map<Id, Custom_Inventory__c> m : l) {
        productIds.addAll(m.keySet());
    }
}
```

or returned from the `getComplexMapObject` method using a simple class with a field for the set and a field for the map and any methods that help.

But if your present code works and there are only ever a few inventory maps I'd stick with the current code.

(The equivalent set for the AccountId values is `complexMap.keySet()`.)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning how to get the `Account` ids, even if it is much more straightforward.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Done.